# How to get response (email , user_info) after login with Facebook? Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers, login, facebook

I am trying to allow login from Facebook without popup, not able to get the response from Facebook.

Here is my fb login link:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?client_id=172112224842242&redirect_uri=http://domain.com/customer/account/facebook">FB LOGIN</a>
```

I am able to redirect to my controller but unable to get the response.
These are the things i have tried:

```
$this->request->getParam('email');

$this->getRequest()->getQuery('email');
```

In both ways not getting any response. Please help me resolve this issue, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get info about user. You can get only "code".

```
$this->_request->getParam('code');
```

After this, you should send a new request and get a token:

```
$str = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . $id . '&redirect_uri=' . $url . '&client_secret=' . $secretKey . '&code=' . $code;
$token = json_decode(file_get_contents($str), true);
```

After that, you should send a new request a get the data:

```
$str = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me?client_id=' . $id . '&redirect_uri=' . $url . '&client_secret=' . $secretKey . '&code=' . $code . '&access_token=' . $token['access_token'] . '&fields=id,name,email,gender';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($str), true);
```

Comment: Thank you @Igor ,  Its working fine. One small concern , With this solution we need to call two API's so it will take time to login. Please suggest if there any simple way.